# Hugo data template telephone number gets rendered as a hash

Tags: hugo

I have a weird problem with Hugo and data templates.

I have link content in a json data template that i try to render inside an `a` tag like so:

data/foobar.json:

`{ [ { link: 'tel:+123123', text: 'a' }, { link: 'mailto:mail@example.com', text: 'b' ] }`

partial.html:

```
{{ range .Site.Data.foobar }}
  <a href="{{ .link }}">{{ .text }}</a>
{{ end }}
```

Which Produces:

```
<a href="#ZgatbplZ">a</a>
<a href="mailto:user@example.com">b</a>
```

For some reason the first anchor target renders out as a random hash, but the second one correctly. This seems to happen only when i start the link with `tel:`, and i can't understand why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably syntax should be: `{{ .link | safeURL }}`

https://gohugo.io/functions/safehtml/

https://gohugo.io/functions/safehtmlattr/#readout

https://gohugo.io/functions/safeurl/

https://gohugo.io/functions/urlize/#readout

This is intentional as the link is not being sanitized.
See docs on Go and the way elements are rendered.
Off the cuff and not near my station - one of the above will point you in the right direction.

Check it and let me know.